# get last child post by wp_query

Tags: wp-query

I have below structure in wp post (custom post type):

> POST
>
> > Child1
> >
> > > Child11 (*)
> > >
> > > Child12 (*)
> >
> > Child2
> >
> > > Child21 (*)
> > >
> > > Child22 (*)
> >
> > Child3

I need to get starred posts by wp_query class (or hooks)

Note: I sure that maximum depth of posts is two.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$posts = get_posts([
    "post_type" => "ABCD", // put the custom type here
    "post_parent__not_in" => "0", // parent is not root
]);
```

Comment: May you please explain how this code helps solve the question?

Comment: I already wrote this code. but wp_query return (Child1, Child2 & Child3) and childs (starred) posts